# get value of the clicked button javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a quiz like "Who wants to be a millionaire?" questions are with random numbers and random operations (+, -, *, //). The user has 4 offered answers - I put 4 buttons with different values. Now, I have a little problem - how can I create a VARIABLE that will take the value of the button the user clicked. I will create a "while" loop which will make random numbers and random operations and it will work as long as that VARIABLE is equal to the result. My problem is that I don't know which button was clicked.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
       <div class="col-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 my-pola">
           <button id="first">1</button>
       </div>
    <div class="col-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 my-pola">
           <button id="second">2</button>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
       <div class="col-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 my-pola">
           <button id="third">3</button>
       </div>
    <div class="col-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 my-pola">
           <button id="fourth">4</button>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: You should consider putting up some code, you know...what you have done so far. That way, we can help you

Comment: Please take a look at these resources on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you don't show us a clear example of your problem we will not be able to provide a clear solution.

Comment: In a properly assigned click handler function, the button's properties can be read using `this.value` or `this.innerText` or what have you.

Comment: @beginner18 Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65767120/edit) your answer to incorporate your code, as the question (not the comments!) should have all the relevant information to your question. You can also read up on [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: please edit the question and put the code there, not in a comment

Comment: i edited now sorry

Answer (score 1):

When you add the button add a value to be passed to it's onclick event handler.
There are many ways of doing this that are more elegant that the rest of my answer.
See event handling also jquery and looking at parent items.

For a simple answer to the basic question

Example:

```
<button onclick="butpress(1,value1)">button 1</button>
OR
<button onclick="butpress(3,'*')">button 3</button>
```

Comment: This would work, however onclick isn't recommended as the javascript should be separated from the html to make things simple.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend putting a class name on all the buttons you need to add an event listener to. Then, you could select all of the buttons and add an event listener to all of them. In the event listener callback function, you can use the event object to determine which button the user has clicked, and write code accordingly.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
 buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
 alert("Hey you just clicked the " + e.target.id + " button!")
 
 })
 }
 /*CODE EXPLANATION:
 We are using querySelectorAll to select all elements that have the corresponding class name. We are going through a for loop so that we can add an event listener to all the items in querySelectorAll. The event object listens to the target and gets the id when the button is clicked. */
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
       <div class="col-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 my-pola">
           <button id="first" class = "btn">1</button>
       </div>
    <div class="col-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 my-pola">
           <button id="second" class = "btn">2</button>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
       <div class="col-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 my-pola">
           <button id="third" class = "btn">3</button>
       </div>
    <div class="col-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 my-pola">
           <button id="fourth" class = "btn">4</button>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: i have while (true) loop and generate 2 random numbers and random operation(+ - * //) and on 4 buttons is printed 4 different answers. Now i need to stop while loop, but i have to know which button was clicked and his value that I can compare with result and if result != value of clicked button => break;

Comment: Well, I already gave you a start. You could use e.target.value to compare the values with if statements I guess. Hope I helped :)

Comment: Thank You for your time but I can't solve it :)

Comment: maybe the answer above could help

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're describing might better match an [`input` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input), either `input[type="radio"]` or `input[type="button"]`.

### Radio inputs

If the player will review their selection before answering, consider [radio inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio). A trade-off here is writing validation code to check if the player picked an answer:

```js
function alertAnswer() {
  /* The important part of this query selector is the `:checked` pseudo-class identifying the player's choice. The root of the selector could be however your selector your input elements, here I've used tag and name attribute for demo purposes only. */
  const choice = document.querySelector('input[name="choice"]:checked');
  if (!choice) {
    alert('Please choose your answer.');
  }
  else {
    alert(choice.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="question">What is one plus one?</p>
<label>
  <input name="choice" type="radio" value="1">
  1
</label>
<label>
  <input name="choice" type="radio" value="2">
  2
</label>
<label>
  <input name="choice" type="radio" value="3">
  3
</label>
<label>
  <input name="choice" type="radio" value="4">
  4
</label>
<button type="submit" onclick="alertAnswer()">Answer</button>
```

### Button inputs

If player submits their choice as soon as they choose it like you've described in your question, consider [input buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button). Semantically the important different here between an input and a button is our choice elements have a `value` attribute, making it simpler to use it to submit an answer. A trade-off here is the input value *must* be the same as the display value.

```html
<p class="question">What is one plus one?</p>
<input type="button" value="1" onclick="alert(value)">
<input type="button" value="2" onclick="alert(value)">
<input type="button" value="3" onclick="alert(value)">
<input type="button" value="4" onclick="alert(value)">
```